# How to use C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to generate a word document with repeated table header which is not on the first row in the first page?

Tags: c#, ms-word, tableheader

Now I am going to use C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to implement the functionality of repeated table headers across multiple pages in a word document. However, the expected output Word document (please refer to the URL [Sample Word Document](https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx?cid=8ffa4a1c66cfced9&page=view&resid=8FFA4A1C66CFCED9!1071&parId=8FFA4A1C66CFCED9!1070&app=Word) for a sample document) is quite special at the requirement of repeated table header: the table header (see the row with the blue background) is in the third row on the first page, but will be in the first row as normal across all subsequent pages.

Please kindly advise on a solution. You are welcome to give some sample C# codes on this regard.
Thanks.

Comment: `Table.Rows[3].HeadingFormat = true;` maybe?

Comment: No that will not work. It is not possible to specify a row to form the header without all rows above it being included. The only workable solution in this case is to split the table above the required header row. @moonriver1902: As per StackOverflow's posting standards, please edit your post to include your current 'problem' code.

Comment: @Charlieface, if you set as Table.Rows[3].HeadingFormat = true, then in all the subsequent pages, the blue background will fall on the 3rd row instead of the first row as expected. I have tested your solution, but it cannot work as expected in all the subsequent pages.